# What's the recommended way to format currency symbols in a locale-agnostic way?

Tags: currency-formatting, java-money, jsr354

### Context

I want to have a standard way of formatting prices regardless of the locale. Currently, the output format is locale-aware (as with `NumberFormat`):

| Monetary amount | Format with locale es-ES | Format with locale en-US |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Money.of(1234, "EUR") | 1.234,00 € | EUR1,234.00 |

Generated with [this gist](https://gist.github.com/gastonfournier/8a34876c69009d9caf9329c7ddc03cc9/9038a4b42b4ba530601f3e436f4d8d0ce4fd8ab9)

### Questions:

1. Do you see any problem with this? Perhaps I'm not considering some consequences of this decision
2. What's the best way of accomplishing this with Moneta?

### Workaround

I've been able to get the desired output by overriding the Locale in the `AmountFormatQueryBuilder` to [force it use the locale I prefer](https://gist.github.com/gastonfournier/ab8d3e8737371f8be2787fd834462a00/cca4e06fd928bbbe6ffa4b33c6f60b08d49e208b):

```java
    static String format(Money money, Locale locale) {
        MonetaryAmountFormat formatter = MonetaryFormats.getAmountFormat(
            AmountFormatQueryBuilder.of(locale)
                .set(CurrencyStyle.SYMBOL)
                .setLocale(EUR_OVERRIDDEN_LOCALE)
                .build()
        );
        return formatter.format(money);
    }
```

but this would require having a `Map<Currency, Locale>` that will hold the desired locale for each currency that should be extracted from the `MonetaryAmount`.

This solution looks like a workaround and I just want to get some insights from the community.

Comment: as far I remember something similar was discussed here  https://github.com/JavaMoney/jsr354-ri/issues/297

Comment: Thanks @SergeyPonomarev, I think the point could be similar in the sense that we both want to be able to tweak the default behaviour. In this case, en-US does not format Euros as € when using symbol style and we want our users to see €, so I'm trying to figure out a way of specifying € as the symbol for EUR, but I don't mind so much about the position (which could become our next challenge)

Comment: Sorry, that a comment that I wrote https://github.com/JavaMoney/jsr354-ri/issues/307#issuecomment-531154409
As far I remember I proposed to make toString() always formatting the same regardless locale.

Comment: But in the case of your comment, I think `toString()` should have a standard output (i.e. currency code + standard number format), but I actually want to format the monetary amount in a particular way, which fits better with a formatter. Mainly, I want to find a recommended way to have a default format for a currency regardless of the locale, but still don't lose the ability to specify a specific format for some locale (e.g. for RTL languages). Please, let me know if the question is not clear

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I think the answer to this question is here: https://github.com/JavaMoney/jsr354-ri/blob/master/moneta-core/src/main/asciidoc/userguide.adoc#42-registering-your-own-formats

By registering a new format using the JSR’s SPI mechanism, we can override the default format and have it work the way we want